# ng: command not found while creating new project using angular-cli

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Installed angular-cli globally using (`npm install -g angular-cli`) but when I'm trying to create project using `ng new my-project` it is throwing error:

> ng: command not found

Comment: what happens when you type ng --help? This was also posted on angular cli repository. check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/503)

Comment: Even when I type ng --help same issue ng: command not found, in issue log there are suggesting to use nvm but I would like to use npm. I tried to correct the path by adding alias in my .profile but already proxy settings are there, so how can I add new path using alias = alias ng="Users/xxxx/npm/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng"

Comment: Can you post your os version as well as your npm version

Comment: Using Mac os, npm version - 2.14.20 & node version - 4.4.0

Comment: Can you verify it is intalled via... `npm ls --global --depth 0`

Comment: yes i installed globally, solution to fix this issue is to set path of ng in .profile but now I am getting new error as                                                                  (node:25315) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
/Users/pkodiya/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/pkodiya/.config/configstore/ember-cli.json'
You don't have access to this file.

Comment: @lego take a look at this comment it will point you in the right direction to get past that error... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/345#issuecomment-201276673

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: try to uninstall your node and install node version 8.10.0.

Answer (score 319):

The issue is simple, `npm` doesn't know about `ng`

Just run `npm link @angular/cli` and it should work seamlessly.

Comment: Can you explain bit more about this?

Comment: @PardeepJain: link command basically creates a global link and then links the global installation target into your project’s node_modules folder.

Comment: @lego : I think the answer deserves acceptance. Please accept if it worked for you.

Comment: Doesn't work sorry. 

`alias ng="PATH-TO-GLOBAL/.npm-global/bin/ng" ( Location of ng file in npm folder)`

This did the trick.

Comment: This worked. Just had to run with `sudo`. `sudo npm link @angular/cli`.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution is working. I am using windows and can confirm that this solution did work for me. But i had to do something additionally: Run this in powershell: "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted". This allows you to run .ps1 (powershell) files.

Comment: This does not work, regardless whether using sudo or not

Comment: I can confirm that this doens't work.

Answer (score 70):

First, `angular-cli` is deprecated and has been replaced with `@angular/cli`. So if you uninstall your existing angular-cli with `npm uninstall angular-cli`, then reinstall the package with the new name @angular/cli you might get some conflicts. My story on Windows 7 is:

I had installed angular-cli and reinstalled using `npm install -g @angular/cli`, but after doing some config changes to command-line tools, I started getting the ng command not found issue. I spent several hours trying to fix this but none of the above issues alone worked. I was able to fix it using these steps:

Install [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/about) and remove any PATH entries for node, npm, angular-cli or @angular/cli. Node.js will be in your System path, npm and angular entries are in the User path.

Uninstall node.js and reinstall the current version (for me 6.11.1).
Run Rapid Environment Editor again and make sure node.js and npm are in your System or User path.
Uninstall any existing ng versions with:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean
```

Delete the *C:\Users\%YOU%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular* folder.

Reboot, then, finally, run:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then hold your breath and run:

`ng -v`

If you're lucky, you'll get some love. Hold your breath henceforward every time you run the ng command, because 'command not found' has magically reappeared for me several times after ng was running fine and I thought the problem was solved.

Comment: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Sorry but this is not working.  I tried all the commands above and I used sudo to issue them.  I am on mac OS.

Comment: I followed this format and it worked fine for me without the Rapid Environment Editor. In Windows 10 I manually updated the Paths in the Einvronment Variables. I hadn't run Node or Angular in a while as my last project was dotnet core. So I had to reinstall latest of both npm and node, then reset my paths and reboot before angular/cli uninstall step.

Comment: if "ng -v" does not work try "ng version". This seems to be the command for version check with cli 14

Comment: hey why does at my end in windows terminal `ng -v` doesn't work but `ng v` works

Comment: @Deshan yes that is it, I spent 3 hours repeating same stuff and tweaking path variables but in the end the problem is `ng -v` command itself

Answer (score 34):

Make sure that the npm directory is in your "[**Path**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))" variable.

If the module is installed properly, it may work if you start it out of your global node module directory, but your command line tool doesn't know where to find the `ng` command when you are not in this directory.

For **Win** system variable add something like:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

And if you use a **unix-like terminal** (emulator):

```
PATH=$PATH:[path_to_your_user_profile]/path-to-npm
```

Comment: If you work on multiple projects using different versions of the CLI (so that always running the single global version is not an option), try `export PATH=$PATH:node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng` - it will pick the local version, as long as you run the `ng` command within the root directory of your Angular (sub)project.

Comment: @JanakaBandara how would I add that export command in Win10? Is it ok to add it in the .bash_profile?

Comment: Yup, I usually add that to `.bashrc`

Comment: After doing this make sure you uninstall and reinstall any packages that you installed while it was missing. There's a good chance that their installations are corrupted with a lot of missing dependencies.

I did a fresh install of node v14.17 and npm and wasn't expecting the node installer to fail to add npm to the path. It added nodejs without a problem.
If npm is missing from your path you'll need to reinstall any packages that you installed prior to adding it to the path.
That was my problem with the angular cli. I was looking at angular cli as the problem but npm was the real problem

Answer (score 28):

the easiest solution is (**If you have already installed angular**) :

1 remove the ng alias if existing

```
unalias ng
```

2 add the correct alias

```
alias ng="/Users/<user_name>/.npm-global/bin/ng"
```

3 run ng serve for example and it will work.

Comment: there is no .npm-global directory on Mac

Comment: @pixel for sure there is an npm-global on mac please reference here for further details https://flaviocopes.com/npm-packages-local-global/

Comment: @AchrefGassoumi Thanks but after googling for hours, no location suggesting aliasing to a location would not work.  The only way for me to resolve this was do use nvm as I explained in my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138138/angular-cli-ng-command-not-found-on-mac-os?noredirect=1#comment102663475_58138138

Answer (score 21):

This is how I made it worked for me :).

1 - `npm link @angular/cli`

It will return you the path of **cli**, which will look like this

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.3.0_1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
```

For this part, `/11.3.0_1` please replace this with your respective node version that can be found by typing `node --version`

2 - `cd ~/`

3 - `open .bash_profile`

In the bash profile create an **alias** for **cli** like this,

`alias ng="/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.3.0_1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"`

4 - `source ~/.bash_profile`

This is how your `.bash_profile` will look like once you add **alias** to it.

[image]

Now typing `ng` in the terminal will display output shown in attached snapshot.

[image]

I hope this answer will be helpful.

Comment: Just `npm link @angular/cli` was enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 17):

For Mac run

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

then run

```
alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

Check if working

```
ng version
```

Comment: I had to use following alias command:- alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"

Answer (score 16):

In my case install angular cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**update Nodejs to latest**, then all should work fine.

...and if you still have that problem, it maybe because you run the command in shell and not in cmd (you need to run command in cmd), check this out and maybe it helps...

Answer (score 15):

Run below commands:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

`alias ng="C:/Users/itaas/.npm-global/ng"`  ( Location of ng file in npm folder)

And finally run :

```
ng -v
```

[image: Ng-v]

Comment: With angular 7 i guess this has changed to $ng version

Comment: While this solves one problem, it creates another. This will always mean that  you are running NG from global and never from the application level.

Comment: No it's not like that here we are re-defining ng keyword. There is nothing like app level. it's just config file for current user

Answer (score 15):

If you have installed angular cli globally but **ng** isn't working, just do this:

```
echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

ng --version
```

Comment: C:\>echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: This command is only for Unix/Linux users. If you're on Windows, The Angular CLI should be install in administrator mode.

Answer (score 14):

I've solved the same issue with adding an alias like:

```
alias ng="path-to-your-global-node-modules/angular-cli/bin/ng"
```

Comment: This worked fine for me, but every time when I login I had to do it, so I added it in my .bashrc file in this way: "nano ~/.bashrc" and then added following line there: alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" I am running ubuntu 14.04 on vagrant

Answer (score 14):

I was facing same issue, I was using git bash terminal, I installed angular cli using this command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

but when I try to create new app it was giving me error ng: command not found, I just restarted my pc and it worked, even closing and opening terminal again will also fix issue sometimes

Answer (score 8):

Adding `%AppData%\npm` to the Win path have worked for me.

Source : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1183 , the first comment.

Answer (score 5):

Same problem here running ***Windows 10 x64 / NodeJS 6.9.1 / npm 3.10.9***. 
 After installation of Angular CLI via npm:

> 'ng' command cannot be found

Do the following:

1. Uninstalled npm with `npm uninstall -g npm`
2. Uninstalled NodeJS via control panel / programs and features
3. Downloaded and ran 'old' *NodeJS installer release 6.5.0* from https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.5.0/ (*node-v6.5.0-x64.msi*).
4. After NodeJS 6.5.0 installation completed, open powershell and `npm install -g angular-cli`
5. Grab quick coffee
6. After installation completed, ng worked OK.

HTH

Answer (score 5):

Make sure **angular-cli** is installed before trying to create a project. Windows users can install **angular-cli** without giving permission to command but MAC users have to use **sudo** before executing the command as follow:

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```

Type a password when asked and press enter to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, check if your npm and node installed properly 
with commands `npm version` and `node -v`.

If they are proper:

1. Find the root global Directory of NPM `npm root -g` (it will
   give you root of your global npm store)
2. Uninstall old angular cli with `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
   and `npm cache clean`
3. Reinstall new Version of angular `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
4. make an Alias of Name ng:

`alias ng="C:/ProgramData/npm/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"`

`alias ng="<ath-to-your-global-node-modules>/<angular cli path till ng>"`
(from answered Oct 20 '16 at 15:30  @m.zemlyanoi )

then to check you can type ng -v

Answer (score 5):

For Mac users:

1) Install @angular/cli globally

```
$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/bin/ng -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

2) Create alias for ng

```
alias ng="/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

Done

Answer (score 5):

try this :

alias ng="~/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"

Answer (score 5):

**For mackBook OS**

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm cache verify
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

try with ng -v if not work then set alias and try

```
alias ng="/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.0.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

Answer (score 3):

if you find this error when you are installing angular-cli, 
`-bash: ng: command not found` try this it works,

After removing Node from your system

```
install NVM from here https://github.com/creationix/nvm
Install Node via NVM: nvm install stable
run npm install -g angular-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you install the node js package? https://nodejs.org/en/
Regards

Answer (score 2):

According to `npm`, the  `angular-cli` has been renamed to `@angular/cli` you can use the following syntax to install it.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 2):

running

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Roaming/npm
```

helped.

Make sure your actual username is in the myusername section

Comment: Someone hand this person a medal. Works likes a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [asdf-vm](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf) you need run `adsf reshim nodejs` to recreate links with global modules.

In my case this resolve my problem, I hope resolve to you all too.

Comment: This worked for `asdf`.. Also please fix the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is that you are using PowerShell and not the command line. If you use Windows PowerShell run:

```
cmd
```

then next try:

```
ng --version
```

if it works run:

```
ng new my-project
```

Answer (score 2):

for me, on Linux:

you can open the .bashrc file from Home then, you will notice the following command right there:

`# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.`
`source <(ng completion script)`

comment out the "source" command that you see above by # sign then, save the file.

`# source <(ng completion script)`

reopen the terminal then, you could use it now.

you can now use the following command instead of ng:

open the working directory where the Angular project is there then, try this command instead:

`$ npm start`

you can open the package.json file and move to the line where the "scripts" key is, move to "start" key then, you will notice the `ng serve` that you were like to type then, you can add host and port from your choice like so:

**"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200"**

Answer (score 1):

soluton for windows operating system only.......
first step:

install nodejs version: nodev 8.1.2

second step:
set up environment variable like: C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs

Third step:
install angular use this command: npm install -g @angular/cli

after installation whereever you have to create project like: ng new first-project......

Answer (score 1):

For me (on MacOSX) I had to do:

```
nvm install stable
npm install -g angular-cli
```

This installed ng into:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

But npm did not put a link to ng into

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

Which was why it was not part of the %PATH and therefore available from the command line except via an absolute address.

So I used the following the create a link to ng:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/\@angular/cli/bin/ng /usr/local/bin/ng
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Go to C:\Users{{users}}\AppData\Roaming and delete the npm folder
2. Uninstall node and install it again
3. Run the command to install angular cli

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Repairing NodeJS installation on windows resolved it for me.

Comment: Yesterday my problem was fixed by doing an npm update, but today THIS fixed my problem today.  I wonder what tomorrow's will be.  I dont understand why this keeps 'breaking'

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I had the same issue on windows. The thing that baffled me most on this was I have had Node installed since Angular 4 dabbling here and there. And sure enough. That was my problem. I needed to upgrade node.

Just installing the newest version worked fine for me without having to do any of the above steps post the new install

Answer (score 1):

Maximum time, this is a path issue conflict between npm and angular cli.

The solution that worked for me ->

1. **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming** Paste this in File Explorer and delete **npm** folder.
2. **npm install -g @angular/cli@latest** run this command to reinstall latest angular cli.
3. **npm link @angular/cli** now this command can solve your path issue

Literally that three steps will fix your issue, otherwise you need to update environment variable by search and open **Edit the system environment variables**

Ariful Ahsan
https://arifulahsan.com

Answer (score 1):

You can probably come across this issue in many other ways, but this is what my scenario was, and if you have the same scenario this answer will help, or give you some knowledge.

### The Scenario:

1. You did NOT install nodejs through package manager, but rather you downloaded the binaries and saved at some path. I saved mine at `/opt/node-v18.15.0`.
2. You did NOT add to the PATH variable the path to `node`, `npm` etc. rather you symlinked `node`, `npm` and `npx` to some well-known location. I created the symlinks at `/usr/bin`.

Now, if you install `@angular/cli` using `npm install -g @angular/cli` and then try to use `ng`, you will get the error:

```
ng: command not found
```

Note that installing `@angular/cli` creates the `ng` file (which is essentially a symlink to `../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js`) at the same location as the `node`, `npm` and `npx` files are located, which for me was `/opt/node-v18.15.0/bin`. The reason you get this error is that this path is not in your PATH variable as you never added it!

### Solution:

Add the node path to the PATH variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/node/bin
```

That way you won't need to create the symlinks to `node`, `npm` etc. AND if any other npm package installation creates some other commands like `ng` in the `bin` folder, you will not face issues like this again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in **windows 7** and you can not run command start with **ng**

please, update the angular/CLI at once and try to use ng commands

use below comman to update latest CLI

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

This works to update your angular/cli
//*Global package (cmd as administrator)

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install '@angular/cli' by using npm as global module

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After that try to ping the cli by using 'ng' command from the terminal window.If any problem like

> Command 'ng' not found

Then you need to manually setup the

> ng

command availability.You set this step by running the following command.

```
ln -s path-to-your-ng-command /bin
```

eg:

sudo ln -s /opt/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng /bin/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was happening when I restarted working on an adjacent tab. It was the npm which was not set. Please check the version of npm wither using

> npm -v

or if you are having nvm then

> nvm list

or

> nvm current

I set it to 8.9.1 and then it started working again.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was simply running the wrong node version.

I had just previously installed a new node version to play around with Angular (2). 
At work we use 6.x so that is my default in nvm. After restarting the laptop `ng` stopped working simply because I was running node 6.x again. So for me it was simply a matter of using the version with which I was installing the Angular CLI:

```
nvm use node // with the node alias pointing to the right version
```

or

```
nvm use v8.11.3 // if you happen to know the version
```

Check your installed versions and aliases with

```
nvm list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MacOS computer (mine is MOJAVE 10.14.2), just add these lines to the end of your **~/.bash_profile file**:

```
export ANGULAR=~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/ng
export PATH=$ANGULAR:$PATH
```

Notice that v10.8.0 is the version of my installed Node.js. To get which version is yours, run this:

```
node --version
```

When done, reload it via your terminal/bash:

```
cd ~
source .bash_profile
```

After doing these steps you should be able to run your **ng** binary file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have zsh installed add alias to .zshrc file in home directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use enterprise computer and unable to access system environments

use **RapidEE** to edit user variables
then add to path these

```
%AppData%\npm
```

or

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

it worked for me on windows

Answer (score 0):

Permanently solution here for MACOS Users:

open terminal:

```
sudo vim /etc/Paths
```

add new line. (INSERT , press fn+i)

```
/Users/[your-user]/.npm-global/bin
```

press ESC , and then :wq  (exit from editor)

restart terminal (close and open terminal again..)
check the path;

```
~ % echo $PATH
```

it should be listed in path list now.. like below;

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/[myuser]/.npm-global/bin ....
```

good job,  ng command now,

ng version

```
Angular CLI: 14.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything here, what solved my issue was:

1. Making sure I have the latest `node.js` version (re-install from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Running the commands from the `powershell`