# ng command not found angular-cli when create new project in windows

Tags: node.js

i am successfully install node.js and angularjs2 using this command. node version is

```
node version v6.9.1

npm install -g angular-cli
```

and the installation path is that

```
C:\Users\Arobil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin
```

which are include

```
system->advanced system setting->Environment variable->path
```

but the problem is that when i create new project using angular
its

D:>ng new app
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Am i missing anything?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227794/ng-command-not-found-while-creating-new-project-using-angular-cli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: i found the solution for that problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/46874999/7968316

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Uninstall Everything
>       npm uninstall -g angular-cli

```
 npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

 npm cache clean
```

> 2. Re-install

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Now have a look in your global NPM folder, it should be something like "/Users//.npm-global/bin/". In here you should see your angular CLI files. To test if everything works, try typing:

```
 ng -v
```

If this does not work, then try manually adding an alias that mappings ng to your ng folder, like so:

```
 alias ng="/Users/<username>/.npm-global/bin/ng"
```

I've also had issues where I have not had 'sudo' permissions. To get around this you can change your global path. To do this you can do something like this within your ~/.bash_profile :

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
```

Taken from [here](http://www.jondjones.com/frontend/angular/troubleshooting/how-to-fix-ng-command-not-found-on-a-mac)

Comment: `ng -v` does not seem to be a valid command. Did you mean `ng --version`?

Comment: this is not working and I dont have /Users/username/.npm-global directory

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add path in Your Environment Variable.
To do this, follow these steps.
go to my computer properties >> advanced system settings >> environment variable >> add new variable and assign path to your NPM.

For Example my NPM path:-

path : D:\Users\goldy.b\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 3):

I am using Mac and this worked for me.

alias ng="/Users/Batman/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your angular cli with npm using

`npm link @angular/cli`

That worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just change your project name and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

After making an entry to the path variable for C:/Users/{userName}/Appdata/Roaming/npm folder, run the following command 
**npm config get prefix** and check whether the output is consistent with the above one i.e. C:/Users/{userName}/Appdata/Roaming/npm.

If the path is not same, make sure that you run the command **npm config set prefix "APPDATA\Roaming\npm"**. Now once you install the angular/cli using -g all corresponding packages will be downloaded in this folder and you will be able to run ng commands from any directory of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Windows consider that Power Shell does not support Angular CLI commands... try with command prompt (and remember to open with administrator rights!)

Comment: I thought powershell could run any command that cmd could