# Angular - ng: command not found

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line

I'm trying to learn Angular and my knowledge in terminal is beginner. After I installed Angular and then type `ng new my-project`. I get the response `ng: command not found`. I've seen other posts that had this problem and I've uninstalled and reinstalled *npm* and *ng*.

> The last step I took was npm install -g @angular/cli@latest then ng new my-project.

Then I get `ng: command not found`.

Comment: Version of npm? node? what operating system do you use? All those relate to this problem. Please update your question

Comment: Have you checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227794/ng-command-not-found-while-creating-new-project-using-angular-cli

Comment: *As an aside:* if you work on multiple projects using different versions of the CLI (so that always running a single global version is not an option), try `export PATH=$PATH:node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng` - it will pick the local version (relative to the current directory), as long as you run the `ng` command from within the root directory of your Angular (sub)project.

Answer (score 130):

Guess You are running on **Windows**
(To make [@jowey's answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623571/angular-ng-command-not-found/46632394#46632394)r more straightforward).

- Install Angular normally from your **bash** `$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
  Next is to rearrange the PATHS to
- NPM
- Nodejs
- Angular CLI

in System Environment Variables, the picture below shows the arrangement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to add:C:\Users\"MY-USERNAME-HERE"\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: @Adedoyin: what exactly do you need to find in your path ending with @angular/cli?  ng binary is located inside of bin/ (or in the folder specified at the next line).

Comment: ´npm ls´ lists the local repository and ´npm ls --global´ lists the global repository. The path to the repository is printed out in the first line. Add both just to be sure

Comment: I had to add the bin folder of angular CLI to the path `\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I took 2-3 week to find the solution until find yours.

Comment: this is still valid, it worked for me

Answer (score 69):

I had that same problem and just solved it.

make sure you have node installed.

after running

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

when installation is finished, try re-opening your git bash or whatever you're using or open it in a new folder. boom. it worked for me

Answer (score 48):

The error may occur if the `NodeJs` is installed incorrectly or not installed at all.
The proper way to fix that is to install/reinstall it the right way (check their [official website](https://nodejs.org/) for that), but if you're searching for a quick solution, you can try to install Angular CLI globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If it doesn't work and you are in a hurry, use `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Don't forget to reopen your terminal window.

Comment: doesn't work. even if installed with sudo, the ng command is still not found. the $PATH isn't updated at all.

Comment: If you need sudo for npm you have an improper installation of npm.

Comment: @Bon, you're totally right! Installation with `sudo` is just a quick fix

Comment: All I had to do was to uninstall the existing nodejs and reinstall it from the nodejs website.  The one from my computer was from the corporate approved software.

Answer (score 12):

**For MacOS**

Sometimes the `ng` command does not get established as a link in `/usr/local/bin`. I fixed the problem by adding it manually:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng /usr/local/bin/ng
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works. My ng path is `/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.6.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng`

Comment: Worked for me too. My ng path with Node 12 and Angular 11 turned out to be: `/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng`

Answer (score 12):

If you have already installed `@angular/cli`

Then you only need to link it to npm using `npm link @angular/cli`

Otherwise first install angular by `npm install @angular/cli` and then link.

Comment: This worked for me (npm link @angular/cli) - commenting to register date

Answer (score 10):

> - First of all check by running
>   **npm config get prefix**

- It should return some thing like **(C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm)**
- if it does not return it.
- run  **npm config delete prefix**
- then run **npm install -g @angular/cli@latest**
- And check by running **ng --version**
- It has solved my problem. Hope it will help you.

---

**

Comment: on linux npm get prefix gives /usr/local, the ng executable is at /usr/local/bin/ng
and is a symbolic link to ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js

Answer (score 8):

It may has not helped OP, but it solved my problem. This answer is to help others who have not tried the command mentioned in OP's question.

Just use `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`. It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 7):

if you install npm correctly in this way:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and still have that problem, it maybe because you run the command in shell and not in **cmd** (you need to run command in cmd), check this out and maybe it helps...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue in Windows. I could solve it by running the ng command with `npm`

```
ng g c test

Error : C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

**Solution :**

```
$ npm run ng g c test
```

Other solution worked for me to use Windows PowerShell or command prompt instead of bash shell

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time developers install just Node.js and start working on development. This issue related angular cli dependency on your development environment.

You can fix this with command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are working on Windows then do the following:

From this directory:

**C:\Users\ [your username] \AppData\Roaming** , delete **NPM folder** then install Angular using this command **npm install -g @angular/cli**

Answer (score 5):

***Windows only***

The clue is to arrange the entries in the path variable right.

As the [NPM wiki tells us](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows):

> Because the installer puts C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs before C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm on your PATH, it will always use version of npm installed with node instead of the version of npm you installed using npm -g install npm@.

So your path variable will look something like:

> `C:\<path-to-node-installation>;%appdata%\npm;`

Now you have to possibilities:

1. Swap the two entries so it will look like

```
…;%appdata%\npm;C:\<path-to-node-installation>;…
```

This will load the npm version installed with npm (and not with node) and with it the installed Agnular CLI version.

2. If you (for whatever reason) like to use the npm version bundled with node, add the direct path to your global Angualr CLI version. After this your path variable should look like this:

```sh
…;C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli;C:\<path-to-node-installation>;%appdata%\npm;…
```

or

```sh
    …;%appdata%\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli;C:\<path-to-node-installation>;%appdata%\npm;…
```

for the short form.

This worked for me since a while now.

Answer (score 5):

**Windows 10 Only**

If you are using **Git Bash** and also you are sure that you have done all steps that are listed above, still getting an error like this, run following command:

```
alias ng="C:/Users/<your-username>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

then run `ng -v`

Finally, it works if you see the version of Angular-CLI

Comment: but every time I start my vs code I have to do this in order to run ng commands. Please help.

Comment: put it into your .bash_profile or your .bash_rc

Answer (score 4):

100% working solution

1) `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

2)`brew uninstall node`

3)`echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc`

4)`brew install node`

5) `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Finally and most importantly

6) `export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"`

Also if any editor still shown err than write

7) point over there .

100% working

Comment: At the end I runned `npm install` then `npm start`

Comment: At the `ClientApp` directory

Comment: Perfect! it works for me but after a few times. (also I had an issue with brew (did not have it and had and issue with installing it solution here: https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/666#discussioncomment-4507934))

Answer (score 4):

Before wasting lots of time in installing and uninstalling, read this.

If you already installed angular before and found this issue, may be it is the reason that you installed angular before with running terminal as Administrator and now trying this command without administrator mode or vice versa. There is a difference in these two.

If you installed angular without administrator mode you can only use angular commands such as ng without administrator mode. Similarly,

If you installed angular with administrator mode you can use angular commands such as ng in administrator mode only.

Answer (score 4):

if you have npm, install run the command

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

then bind your ng using this:

`cd`

```
alias ng=".npm-global/bin/ng"
```

Follow the Pictures for more help.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It worked for me on a mac environment as a quick workaround. However, I need to run the commands every time with a new terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

Removing NODE and using NVM instead fixed a lot of issues.

> removing Node from your system
>
> install NVM from here https://github.com/creationix/nvm
>
> Install Node via NVM: nvm install
>
> stable run npm install -g angular-cli

[**LINK**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/503)

Comment: If you are using nvm and have more than one version of node installed, make sure you are using the same version of node that you used when you installed Angular.  I keep forgetting this.

Answer (score 2):

You can install `npx` to use Angular CLI installed in your directory:

```
npm install -g npx
npx ng serve
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** : Delete "npm" folder from the following path

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming
```

**Step 2** : Once you have the "npm" folder deleted, uninstall Node.Js.

**Step 3** : Reinstall Node.JS

**Step 4** : Install Angular CLI Using this command `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

**Step 5**: Now try : `ng --version` or `ng -v`

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of issues installing it on a mac with all the permission errors
Finally the following line solve the issue.

```
sudo npm i -g @angular/cli
```

---

Comment: This downloaded the missing components for me and then the gradle wrapper downgraded to the correct version for the project.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and everything worked by changing the npm directory.

```
         mkdir ~/.npm-global
         npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
         export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
         source ~/.profile
         npm install -g jshint
         ng --version
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> npm uninstall -g angular-cli
>> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

>> npm cache clean
```

Restart you machine

then `>> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

set Path : C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli

Hope you never get 'ng' not found

Answer (score 1):

I'll add this as "yet another option" which worked for me when none of the other options worked( on windows ).

You can run the angular binary via its full path name.
node C:\Users\user\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng.js --version

Oddly enough, adding these paths to my env didn't work...for some reason windows opened editor to edit ng.js file instead of running it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer on this page worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54633995/2347595

Using the git bash terminal, I noticed that when I `npm install -g @angular/cli` and then check the `~/AppData/Roaming/npm/` directory, it contains 3 files:

- ng
- ng.cmd
- ng.ps1

Then in my git bash terminal I typed the following to extend the `$PATH` to point to this top-level npm directory: `export PATH=$PATH:~/AppData/Roaming/npm/`

I was then able to run `npm version` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You must know the full path of your angular installation.
For example: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng .
Type in cmd, powershell or bash

```
alias ng="C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng"
```

Answer (score 0):

**In my case**

**OS Version:** `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`

**Node version** `v12.16.0`

Remove **ng** from `/usr/local/bin` by using below command.

`sudo rm -r ng`

After that, installed **ng** by using command mentioned below.

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

For Linux user

```
$ alias ng="/home/jones/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

then check angular/cli version

```
ng --version
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnaM4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess everyone figured this out years ago but me. simple ng stopped working when I updated node. I tried all the previous suggestions in this thread to no avail but this is my solution. the command npm ng works but darn it I want just ng to work. So
I created a bat filed named ng.bat with this content

npm ng %*

either put ng.bat in a directory recognized by path or add a new path in This Computer / Properties / Advanced System Settings / Environment Variables/ System Variables / Path  . For instance I added C:\Shortcuts to path.

EDIT the above answer is not THE REAL SOLUTION. What npm need is to find the npm-cli.js which is located in the npm bin directory. If a path is not set to bin then not work. I just copied npm-cli.js and put it in the npm directoy which has a path set to it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows oriented:

> If you're chasing an "update node/angular and I wiped my AppData
> folder and now the world hates me stream of errors", then this may help.

Clear out Environment Variable settings for Node/npm/@angular/cli (They don't help)

Install Node.JS/npm from https://nodejs.org/en/ (Remember where you install it)

Confirm the location npm is [currently] running from:

```
npm config get prefix
```

Realize that is not where you just install new/fresh Node.

Update npm global pointer (which is not an environment variable)

```
npm config set prefix "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

Reinstall Angular

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Check angular install

```
ng --version
```

Hopefully this helps someone. Sorry, you'll have to reinstall any other interesting packages.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was something with node. Version was very wrong somehow.

Uninstalled node from "Add or remove programs" and then re-installed it using the file from their website.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue,

1. If you are using VSCode, then start with installing @angular/cli globally within the VSCode terminal, since you already did this go ahead and check ng version in **windows command terminal**.
2. It will prompt you some Nodejs versions that are needed for compatibility with Angular CLI(pls refer the screenshot)
   [image], use nvm to install and use the latest nodejs version as prompted by the terminal. (i.e. nvm install  nvm use  )
3. Once you have an appropriate version of npm, check the ng version in Windows command terminal again: [image: Successful ng version]

Now you can move ahead with using ng in your code editor's terminal.

4. Also ensure you have the PATH variables set as the bottom three in the below screenshot.
   [image: set PATH variables]

Answer (score -6):

just install npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer, it is already stated in the question that this has been tried.