# When trying to install angular, ng command is not found

Tags: angular

After installing angular, I tried the ng -v command though it keeps showing me the command is not found.

node vsn 12.9.1
npm vsn 6.10.2

I have tried reinstalling, and tried uninstalling angular.

/na

-bash: ng: command not found

Comment: What command are you using to install? Are you using npm or yarn, are you installing global or as dev dependency, this is tough to diagnose without more information.

Comment: @ChrisW. npm install -g @angular/cli/ global .   just following from the angular website

Comment: Do you get output specifying the installation was successful? You might try the actual whole package and not just cli via `npm install angular`

Comment: It says it is successful for the cli, though as trying for the package it also doesnt work as well.
this is what is outputs; https://pastebin.com/vectB3PA

Comment: I think it's messing up with my react libraries, though not completely sure why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - ng: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623571/angular-ng-command-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue a while back, I had installed and reinstalled multiple times. It turned out I wasn't running the CMD as administrator and it wouldn't let me use the angular CLI

*Solution was to set up and alias like so

```
alias ng="/Users/YourName/.npm-global/bin/ng"
```

Comment: I have tried to install with sudo on mac, though it still gives me the same problem : (

Comment: try to set up and alias  like so 'alias ng="/Users/j.jones/.npm-global/bin/ng"'

Comment: obviously replace the path to match your installation

Comment: This has not resolved my issue.  the .npm-global directory does not exist

Answer (score 0):

None of this helped me, at the end I had to use nvm as described here

[Angular CLI ng command not found on Mac Os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138138/angular-cli-ng-command-not-found-on-mac-os/58207895#58207895)