# @angular-cli install fails with deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated (mac)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

After updating node.js and npm to current LTS:

```
node -v
v12.16.0
```

```
npm -v
6.13.4
```

When I'm trying to *install @angular-cli* following the steps in [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local), running `npm install -g @angular/cli`
 in the terminal stops the installation and the console output is:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
/Users/user/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /USERS/USER/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@9.0.2 postinstall /USERS/USER/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@9.0.2
updated 1 package in 12.202s
```

And in this case, `ng new project-name` yields `-bash: ng: command not found`. Any help would be very welcome as I have a big project coming up.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

The issue you are experiencing has noting to do with `npm warning` you see in console [ref](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16952). It is seems more likely a problem with permissions on your machine or NodeJS installation issue or both.

I would recommend to remove your NodeJS installation completely at first and then install NVM to manage your NodeJS instances:

- Mac/Linux: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
- Windows:https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Once you done installing NVM try to install Angular CLI:

```
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**: Also you  can check this [issue](http://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/503)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great reply! Unfotunatley this didn't work as when running `ng new` terminal still prints out `-bash: ng: command not found` . This is pretty weird as I've uninstalled and reinstalled node.js and angular-cli. Maybe this a permissions issue on the computer?

Comment: @BenMordechai are you using NVM now?

Comment: Yes, I've installed nvm and checked it's installation

Comment: @BenMordechai did you remove the nodejs installation before installing NVM? Also checkout this issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/503

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Request package was **deprecated**.
and that according to Mikeal Rogers (creator of request) read this [link](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)

and for more information, you can read this [article](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/02/12/requiem_for_request/)

Answer (score 2):

I removed "node_modules" folder & "package-lock.json" file and then execute following 2 commands:

```
npm init

npm install
```

And then, it worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

I tried cleaning cache and it worked for me.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 1):

The package request is now fully deprecated. So that will probably take a while to change. I think the solution would be for angular cli to release a new version that is not reliant upon request.

Comment: Request is still maintained and works fine. This issue is not related to request being deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and installing `angular cli` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

$brew install angular-cli

Installed angular9.0.3(stable)
This depends on node13.08.0

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in my Angular 9 project, I just copy pasted **node_modules** folder from my old angular project, I worked fine, Please try this way if nothing worked out. but you will get the same issue if you do **npm install**, pls don't do.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local), using a Windows 10 machine, to install Angular CLI in a machine with NodeJS and npm package manager

```
node -v
# v12.16.0

npm -v
# 6.13.4
```

the first time running

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

got similar message to yours

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

C:\Users\tiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\tiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@10.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\tiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@10.0.0
added 269 packages from 206 contributors in 97.901s
```

Then, when running a second time, the message matched yours (notice the last line now doesn't say `added 269 packages`; instead, `updated 1 package`).

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
C:\Users\tiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\tiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@10.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\tiago\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@10.0.0
updated 1 package in 8.691s
```

If I then type

```
ng --version
```

I didn't get an error like you. Instead, got the following result

[image: Angular CLI installed]

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 10.0.0
Node: 12.16.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1000.0
@angular-devkit/core         10.0.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.0
@schematics/angular          10.0.0
@schematics/update           0.1000.0
rxjs                         6.5.5
```

which shows that it actually didn't fail but got Angular CLI installed.

In fact, when I run (with cd to C:/Users/tiago/Desktop/angular)

```
ng new my-app
```

The my-app is created

[image: Angular app here]

and can be served (with cd to my-app)

```
ng serve --open
```

As I can see the following page, this means the installation and setup was successful.

[image: It works]

---

So, as per your case with `-bash: ng: command not found`, this may mean NodeJS wasn't installed properly (I would [reinstall it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46623602/5675325)). If that doesn't solve,  I've seen another [solution to that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58207895/5675325) before; simply follow the next steps

1. Remove Node from your system
2. Install [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)
3. Install Node via NVM: nvm install stable
4. Run `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli

npm install mkdirp

npm cache verify

close the terminal and open it again

ng new newApp

it will work for this issue....

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are facing issue in Windows machine.

Just mention cli version along with the command.

```
npm i @angular/cli@8.1.0
```

This worked for me.

Further , you might need to set path variable if getting below issue

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

This solved my issue in mac