# How to resolve install angular cli issue

Tags: angular-cli, angular8

Tried to install angular cli but getting error.I do not know why i am getting this issue.
How to resolve this error.If anyone know please help to find solution.

```
C:\>npm install -g @angular/cli

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported 
npm ERR! code ENOENT 
npm ERR! syscall rename 
npm ERR! path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\rimraf 
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\.rimraf.DELETE 
npm ERR! errno -4058 
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\rimraf' -> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\.rimraf.DELETE' 
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-24T13_33_12_867Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you share your version of npm ?

Comment: @GaryHoubre: npm version is 6.14.5

Comment: I think this issue can work for you :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235086/angular-cli-install-fails-with-deprecated-request2-88-2-request-has-been-depr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@angular-cli install fails with deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated (mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235086/angular-cli-install-fails-with-deprecated-request2-88-2-request-has-been-depr)

Comment: Can you put this problem solved please :D

Comment: @GaryHoubre: Issue resolved