# Angular Cli - ng command not found in terminal

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Specs:

- MacOS 10.12.6
- Node.js v8.9.4
- NPM 5.6.0

I'm new to programming (and stackoverflow). I installed Angular using the following command in the terminal: npm install -g @angular/cli. I ran into an EACCESS error but [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) resolved it. Initially I was able to run the ng command. But after closing and reopening the terminal, the "ng: command not found" error happened. I removed Angular and reinstalled it. But that didn't help.

[Screenshot of the "ng: command does not exist" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3hi2.png)

[Screenshot of npm list -g --depth=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLnfr.png)

[Errors in uninstalling Angular part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvaPP.jpg)

[Errors in uninstalling Angular part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW7V7.png)

[echo $PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUHcD.png)

Comment: What does typing `npm list -g --depth=0` say

Comment: I tried that before and it says that @angular/cli@1.6.3 is in the following path: /Users/<user name>/.npm-global/lib

Comment: that doesn't sound like a mac.

Comment: Are you running a virtual machine?

Comment: I'm using a mac and using the terminal built into my mac. so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Open a terminal in your mac, run `npm list -g --depth=0` in your mac terminal and share a screenshot or copy paste output. In mac you usually see /usr, /Users is more common in windows.

Comment: Ok, I added the screenshot in the description.

Comment: Try following 3 things,1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` 2. `npm cache verify` 3. `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` (uninstall, clean npm cache, reinstall)

Comment: I'm stuck on step 1. I added two screenshots of the situation in the description.

Comment: How did you install nodejs

Comment: I installed Node from their offical website.

Comment: Recommend resorting to [homebrew approach](https://changelog.com/posts/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x) very friendly mac installing/update for terminal. Will want to uninstall your current node if possible

Comment: I think the problem may be my $PATH. When I was first encountered the the EACCESS error from installing Angular, I thought the solution was to edit the $PATH and add /usr/local/bin/ to it. Ultimately that didn't work and I ended up resolving it from the website I linked in the description. So my $PATH right now might be messed up. I'm just not sure if that's the reason for the ng command issue. I attached a screenshot of my $PATH.

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227794/ng-command-not-found-while-creating-new-project-using-angular-cli

Answer (score 2):

You need to install @angular/cli **globally NOT locally**.
if you type:

> npm install -g @angular/cli

in terminal and you will get the error:
ng: command not found or different error, it's because you do not have access to the global directory of npm

The solution is:
just use sudo

> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: What if you are running into this error on windows, while being admin ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you tried another way of installing nodejs, like using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). 
It is really easy to use and lets you run multiple version of nodejs and npm dependencies on the same machine.

As it is [stated in npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions), EACCESS errors usually go away with the following strategies:

1. Use a Version manager (like Node Version Manager)
2. Change nodejs default installation directory

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs website installation package installed it almost like it expected a pc.
So we're seeing two issues here

- Premission on directory it was installed, which can be fixed with `chmod`
- Location unknown, which can be fixed with `export`

You can export by editing ~/.bash_profile
and adding

```
export PATH="[Enter your path here]:$PATH"
```

But if you're new to this, I highly recommend to resort to helping installing software like [homebrew approach](https://changelog.com/posts/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x) very friendly mac installing/update for terminal.

Will want to uninstall your current node if possible.

Then it's

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew update

brew doctor

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

brew install node

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check your `NODE_PATH` environment variable value ?

```
echo $NODE_PATH
```

If it's empty (and given your default location of installation in MacOS)
try to set it into:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/lib/node
```

To make it more permanent put it inside your `~/.bash_profile`, then restart your terminal (otherwise `source ~/.bash_profile`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an installation of Node and NPM based on Homebrew, your installation may not keep your globally installed packages in a predictable location (mine didn't).

[These steps](http://codermem.com/javascript/angular/install-or-update-ngm-and-angular-on-mac-os/) helped me ensure Angular CLI and other globally-installed packages land in a predictable location and now they work in my terminal.

Summary:

1. Delete any existing NPM packages:

   `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
2. Delete your current installation of Node and NPM:

   `brew uninstall node`
3. Preconfigure NPM to install packages in a location under your home directory:

   `echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc`
4. Add the new NPM packages location to your shell's search path:

   `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
5. Quit and re-launch the Terminal app
6. Install Angular CLI in your fresh Node setup:

   `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Now the `ng` command should exist at `~/.npm-packages/bin/ng` and you should be able to run `ng --version` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="/Users/Enter-Your-own-username/.nvm"
```

The below command will load nvm

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

Type the below commands:

```
nvm install stable

nvm install node
```

Check for the installed version of the node to verify the installation
node version

If you have node installed already then go for the below step:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

And in the same terminal session type the below command:

```
ng version
```

---

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
```

---

Create a new project with:

```
ng new angularProject

ng server angularProject
```

type:

```
localhost:4200
```

That should do the job.