# ng new has stopped working after updating to Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

Today, I updated my angular cli to the latest version and encountered an error that stops me from creating a new Angular project. Following is the error log that I get after executing **`ng new app-name`** :

```
Error: Schematic "ng-new" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
    at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:155:23)
    at CollectionImpl.createSchematic (C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\collection.js:12:29)
    at NodeWorkflow.execute (C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\workflow\node-workflow.js:70:38)
    at Promise (C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:141:22)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NewCommand.runSchematic (C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:140:16)
    at NewCommand.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\new.js:77:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\new.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

In order to solve the problem myself I have reinstalled **angular cli** as well as **npm** more than twice. The versions of packages are as follows:

```
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.0
@schematics/angular          0.6.0
@schematics/update           0.6.0
rxjs                         6.1.0
Angular Cli                  6.0.0
Node                         8.11.1
npm                          5.6.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I ran **ng new** from the place where the angular global packages are installed and I am able to create an an application from there. Running it from anywhere else, produces error.

Comment: I think it doesn't update to Angular 6. How can you update it?

Comment: I did it as explained by @YakovFain, but, to no result. Angular Cli gets updated to version 6 though, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happened to me, I thought that was a bug I reported it  [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10691), it turned out that I had a folder named node_modules on my home directory!

To make sure this is the same issue with you run following commands

```
npm ls -g @schematics/angular
npm ls @schematics/angular
```

If the output of second command contains

```
npm ERR! extraneous: @schematics/angular@0.6.0 C:\Users\User\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@schematics\angular
```

then most likely you have the same issue as it appears that there is a node_modules folder with both the CLI and an old version of @schematics/angular installed locally (C:\Users\User). Remove this to fix this issue.

Please check if it is the case for you too.

Comment: You were right. There was a node_modules folder in the home directory and deleting it solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error when I tried to issue, ng new

I later realized it was as a result of issuing "npm install @angular/cli"  which created a node_modules folder, in the directory I was working.

Remove "node_modules" folder, and create your project now with "ng new"

Ps. with the angular 6 upgrade, the ng team must specify that you cant just run "npm install @angular/cli" anywhere you want, but only in the newly created project. I think this is a bit unfair to the newbies to angular

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your upgrade of Angular CLI didn't go well. Try to uninstall and re-install it again:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

Comment: I did it two times, at least. Between the uninstall and install, I also ran "npm cache verify".

Comment: After this, you may need to link ng with npm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47905173/386579

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall and reinstall it again:
npm ls -g @schematics/angular
npm ls @schematics/angular