# angular-cli not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Trying to create new project using the latest angular-cli i've got some problems.

node -v  v8.11.2

npm -v   6.1.0

ng -v

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.7
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.7
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.7
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.7
@schematics/angular          0.6.7
@schematics/update           0.6.7
rxjs                         6.2.0
typescript                   2.7.2
```

When running `gn new myapp`

```
Error:
Schematic "ng-new" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
Error: Schematic "ng-new" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
at SchematicEngine.createSchematic(C:\...\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:155:23)
```

Comment: [node-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198408/ng-new-has-stopped-working-after-updating-to-angular-6?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) check if this is your issue, if yes mark this post duplicate

Comment: I had same problem what i did is, delete **node_modules** folder in **C:\Users\User\***

Comment: @Timur. Indeed that was the cause. Thank you.