# ng new firstapp in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I want to start a new Angular project but I have the following problem.
please guide me.

[image]

error message

```
Error message: ng: File C: \ Users \ installer \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm \ ng.ps1 cannot be loaded. 
The file C: \ Users \ installer \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm \ ng.ps1 is not digitally signed. 
You cannot run this script on the current system. 
For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, 
see about_Execution_Policies at https: /go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? LinkID = 135170. 
At line: 1 char: 1 + ng new firstapp + ~~ + CategoryInfo: SecurityError: (:) [], 
PSSecurityException + FullyQualifiedErrorId: UnauthorizedAccess.
```

Comment: try use cmd with administrator privilege if it going to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: If you're just starting you might want to start with Angular 9.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198408/ng-new-has-stopped-working-after-updating-to-angular-6

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-system/

Comment: Error message: ng: File C: \ Users \ installer \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm \ ng.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
C: \ Users \ installer \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm \ ng.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system.
For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
https: /go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? LinkID = 135170.
At line: 1 char: 1
+ ng new firstapp
+ ~~
     + CategoryInfo: SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: UnauthorizedAccess.
I've run run as adminstor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why am I suddenly getting: ng : File C:\Users\d\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72863930/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-ng-file-c-users-d-appdata-roaming-npm-ng-ps1-canno)

Answer (score 2):

I start to get this problem recently I found out you need to run this on powershell

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

> The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
>   you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
>   https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
>   [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y

then answer as **Y**

check this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Run below command in Powershell terminal.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```