# Installed Angular Cli by (npm install -g @angular/cli) -- getting ng is not recognised as an external and internal command

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

C:\Users\neha>npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\neha\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\neha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall C:\Users\neha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
>   node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-pre-gyp@0.10.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\neha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back needle@2.2.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\neha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- @angular/cli@6.0.8
  updated 1 package in 37.347s

C:\Users\neha>ng
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227794/ng-command-not-found-while-creating-new-project-using-angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

Just add %AppData%\npm; to the user variable(since %AppData% dir is depending on user) PATH to fix it.

Related issue on **[`Github`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1183)**

Answer (score 0):

You only need to link it to npm using `npm link @angular/cli`

that worked for me