# How can I overcome ng not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng

I have used "npm install -g @angular/cli" to install the angular cli even though I have used the -g it is not installed globally and shows ng not found error constantly I have uninstalled and installed the angular cli many times even I have cleared the cache but it constantly shows the "ng not found" error

Need a solution for how to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked CLI and NPM? If not, you should do that and give it a try. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227794/ng-command-not-found-while-creating-new-project-using-angular-cli?rq=2)

Comment: I have tried that but still that showed the same error  then I uninstalled the git and angular cli and have reinstalled now its working fine. Thanks for your answer